# Scroll flickering issue - using cdk-virtual-scroll with scroll-snap-type

Tags: html, css, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll, scroll-snap-type

I am using [cdk-virtual-scroll](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview).

It is working fine without using the css property `scroll-snap-type` .

When I use `scroll-snap-type`  it is flickering few seconds. herewith I attached the code sample
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gchlgl?file=src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-virtual-scroll-data-source-example.css,src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-virtual-scroll-data-source-example.html

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `cdk-virtual-scroll`, you should define the exact pixel size of your container and item. Because `itemSize` attribute is defining the size of the item. So in your code, the size of the items are same but in responsive size (not fixed using pixel), but you define the `itemSize` is 740px. I thought that will be crash the `cdk-virtual-scroll` to improve performance of your website while doing the calculation of rendering a lot of items.

I've update your code and add attributes `itemSize`, `minBufferPx`, `maxBufferPx`:

#### SEE DEMO: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gchlgl-sf9myn?file=src/app/cdk-virtual-scroll-data-source-example.css)

###### HTML

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
  itemSize="500"
  class="example-viewport"
  minBufferPx="1000"
  maxBufferPx="5000"
>
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of ds" class="example-item">
    <div class="info">{{item}}</div>
    <img
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7913028/pexels-photo-7913028.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1600&lazy=load"
      alt="Girl in a jacket"
    />
  </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

And update some responsive CSS properties to fixed size:

###### CSS

```
.example-viewport {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px; /* updated from 100vh */
}

.example-item {
  height: 500px; /* updated from 100vh */
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 10px !important;
  position: relative;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #0000008a;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 0 0 12px;
}

img {
  height: 500px; /* updated from 100vh */
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: center center;
  object-position: center center;
}
```